# Cart added when user login: Item must be still on the item

Tags: php, mysql, session, cart

I am struggling a bit, i want to find a way when add to cart, that item must be added to cart and be stored. Yes if am new user must register first or login. But still once login successfully that item be kept stored, so can continue to shop more. The current code has no bug no error just i am unable to achieve this properly and need some help with the given logic scenario.

// html code

```
<a href="" class="btn border">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary"></i>
                    <span class="badge"id="cart-badge">0</span>
                </a>
     <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between bg-light border">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0"><i class="fas fa-eye text-primary mr-1"></i>View Detail</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 add-to-cart-btn" data-id="1"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary mr-1"></i>Add To Cart</a>

                    </div>
```

// js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add to cart button click event
    $(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart-btn', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemId = $(this).data('id');

        // Check if the user is logged in
        var isLoggedIn = false; // Set this value based on your authentication logic

        if (isLoggedIn) {
            addToCart(itemId);
        } else {
            showLoginOrRegisterPrompt(itemId);
        }
    });

    // Function to add an item to the cart
function addToCart(itemId) {
  // Send an AJAX request to the server to add the item to the cart
  $.ajax({
    url: 'add-to-cart.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { itemId: itemId },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        // Item successfully added to the cart
        // You can update the UI to reflect the change, such as updating the cart count
        updateCartCount(response.cartItemCount);
        console.log('Item added to cart.');
      } else if (response.status === 'login_required') {
        // User needs to log in or register to continue
        showLoginOrRegisterPrompt(itemId);
      } else {
        // Error adding item to the cart
        console.log('Error adding item to cart.');
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('An error occurred while adding item to cart.');
    }
  });
}


    // Function to show the login or register prompt
function showLoginOrRegisterPrompt(itemId) {
  // Create the modal markup
  var modalContent = `
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginRegisterModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginRegisterModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginRegisterModalLabel">Login or Register</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Login and register form here -->
            <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php">
              <h6>Login</h6>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="loginEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" required>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>

            <hr>

            <form id="registerForm" method="post" action="register.php">
              <h6>Register</h6>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="registerName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerName" name="registerName" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="registerEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registerEmail" name="registerEmail" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="registerPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerPassword" name="registerPassword" required>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  // Append the modal to the body
  $('body').append(modalContent);

  // Show the modal
  $('#loginRegisterModal').modal('show');

  // Remove the modal from the DOM after it's hidden
  $('#loginRegisterModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}

});
```

// login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbName = 'ecommerce_store';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = '';

try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
  $stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);
  $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($user && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
    // valid credentials, store user session
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // set logged_in to true
    header("Location: shopping.php");
    exit();
  } else {
    // invalid credentials
    echo "failure";
  }
}
?>
```

// add-to-cart.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconn.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $itemId = $_POST['itemId'];

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];

        // Add the item to the cart in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO cart (id, product_name) VALUES (:id, :product_name)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $userId);
        $stmt->bindParam(':product_name', $product_name);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Return a success response with the updated cart item count
        $cartItemCount = getCartItemCount($db, $userId);
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'cartItemCount' => $cartItemCount
        );
    } else {
        // User is not logged in
        $response = array('status' => 'login_required');
    }

    // Send the JSON response
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
    // Function to get the count of items in the cart for a specific user
function getCartItemCount($db, $userId) {
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $userId);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}

?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['id']))` - Where are you setting that specific session value? You only set `$_SESSION['user']` (which seems to contain the complete user record) and `$_SESSION['logged_in']`  in the login script.

Comment: Add non-logged-in users' cart items to their Session. If they later log in during that session, transfer the session values to the database. That's how i would do it.

Comment: @ADyson can you perhaps show me an example

Comment: Which part of my suggestion are you unsure about? I assume you know how to add things to the session? And you know how to put things into the database?